standalone-class: convert with dvisvgm - activate the all-pages option
If I want to convert each page of a pdf-file to the same number
of single svg-files, a working command is:
dvisvgm --pdf --page=1- in.pdf out.svg

But if I set this into standalone.cls's convert-option
\documentclass[crop,tikz,
convert={outext=.svg, 
command=\unexpanded{dvisvgm --pdf --page=1- \infile}}, 
%multi=true, % ?
]{standalone}

I get
Class standalone Warning: Conversion unsuccessful!
(standalone)              There might be something wrong with your
(standalone)              conversation software or the file permissions!

Hint: Without the 'all-pages-option' --page=1- it works; but then he produces only one svg-file of page 1.
What do I have to do?
Complete MWE:
% arara: pdflatex: {  shell: yes }  

\documentclass[crop,tikz,
convert={outext=.svg, 
command=\unexpanded{dvisvgm --pdf --page=1- \infile}}, 
%multi=true,
]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\foreach \Letter in {A,2,3,...,10,J,Q,K}{%%
\begin{tikzpicture}% Example:
\node[align=center, draw, rounded corners=1pt, inner sep=1pt,
minimum width=0.5*6ex, minimum height=0.5*9ex,
]{\Letter \\ $\clubsuit$};
\end{tikzpicture}
}%%
\end{document}



I'd suggest to let arara call dvisvgm. To me it seems much cleaner as it separates the LaTeX code from the shell commands processing it. Also, dvisvgm usually produces better results when using DVI instead of PDF files:
% arara: latex
% arara: dvisvgm: { options: [--page=1-] }

\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\foreach \Letter in {A,2,3,...,10,J,Q,K}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[align=center, draw, rounded corners=1pt, inner sep=1pt,
      minimum width=0.5*6ex, minimum height=0.5*9ex,
    ]{\Letter \\ $\clubsuit$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}

